# Isolated UART communication with optocouplers

Tags: uart, communication, opto-isolator, isolation

I want to create a universal PCB for projects requiring galvanic isolation. I'm not in need of fast baud rates, 9600 should suffice. My most common use will be with Arduino 5V/3V3.

I want to ask if this schematic that I created is correct? Is there anything that I could add to make it more versatile?

[image: schematic]

B0505S-1W is 5V to 5V isolated power supply, with required 20mA load current (with my experiments when no load is applied the voltage is higher than 5V). I added J3 jumper because I don't know what will happen if I'd be debugging the low side and back-feed voltage into the +VO|0V of power supply. C1 is supposed to help with interference.

I will probably add more headers during the PCB layout for ease of access during debugging.

Comment: R4,R3 could be higher (10k) unless worst case CTR is satisfied.

Comment: You could also add a 10mA dummy load and 15mA for the LED using 200 ohms for R5

Comment: Scratch the 10k load,  frequency response is poor.  50% CTR for Vce=5 but you want Vce=0.7 non-saturated where hFE drops rapidly below If=5mA thus affecting Voh margin so using 330 with drop = 5-1.2 = 3.8/330R= 11.5 mA with 3.3 -0.7= 2.6 for Voh /1k = 2.6mA results in CTR of 23% required so adequate margin.  The common mode noise must be evaluated to ensure ingress margin with long cables intended.

Comment: Do you really want the max current consumption when idle? Or do you specifically need to detect a break condition? The optos are active high, why not active low?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 So as my knowledge is almost nonexistential about optocouplers, the circuit is correct; just need to fiddle with the values and learn about "CTR"? I've searched the internet for optocuplers circuits for communication as ususally optocouplers invert the signals and mashed them together. Thank you for your input.

Comment: If you multiply the efficacy of emitter detector times hFE you get  CTR. Knowing hFE characteristics depend on both current and Vce when collector base approaches 0 and then becomes positive is saturation which reduces hFE greatly to 10% or so in common emitter mode, but in an emitter follower mode , as in this case, that isn't possible, so you still have adequate CTR but not to the rail.

Comment: C1 will shunt your AC isolation, so be aware of the common mode noise that this may transfer.